# The dispatcher returned from the ServletContext does not support asynchronous dispatching

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have following api returning Flux of String

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/api/getStrListFlux",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> getListOfStr0() {
        return Flux.just("Str-1", "Str-2", "Str-3", "Str-4", "Str-5")
                .log().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    }
```

Whenever I stop the Springboot Application while above method is yet to finish producing all the elements, following exception is thrown

```
2023-09-11T09:05:28.695+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorReturn.ReturnSubscriber)
2023-09-11T09:05:28.698+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : request(1)
2023-09-11T09:05:28.698+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : onNext(Str-1)
2023-09-11T09:05:29.704+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : request(1)
2023-09-11T09:05:29.704+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : onNext(Str-2)
2023-09-11T09:05:30.709+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-2] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : request(1)
2023-09-11T09:05:30.709+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-2] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : onNext(Str-3)
2023-09-11T09:05:31.711+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-3] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : request(1)
2023-09-11T09:05:31.711+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-3] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : onNext(Str-4)
2023-09-11T09:05:32.714+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-4] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : request(1)
2023-09-11T09:05:32.715+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-4] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : onNext(Str-5)
2023-09-11T09:05:32.718+08:00  INFO 2776 --- [     parallel-4] reactor.Flux.OnErrorReturn.1             : onComplete()
Exception in thread "task-6" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The dispatcher returned from the ServletContext does not support asynchronous dispatching
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.dispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.dispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.dispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.dispatch(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.setConcurrentResultAndDispatch(WebAsyncManager.java:405)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startDeferredResultProcessing$8(WebAsyncManager.java:473)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult.setResultInternal(DeferredResult.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult.setResult(DeferredResult.java:243)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.complete(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:223)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.complete(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$AbstractEmitterSubscriber.run(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java. Base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Could not able to find any help. Please explain what is the cause and remedy for this..

I expect that SpringBoot application shutdowns gracefully and there is no error while doing so.

Comment: in order for it to shutdown gracefully u need to set this property `server.shutdown=graceful`. if you dont have it, try with it again

Comment: i ll post the solution as an answer. can you please mark it as right so that the thread gets solved? thanks

Answer (score 0):

in order for it to shutdown gracefully u need to set this property: `server.shutdown=graceful`